# event.currentTarget.name returning as currentTarget

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jsx

I have a handleChange function in typescript that I call within another function to send the value of changes in a text field to a mobx tree. However, when I set `const { name } = event.currentTarget` and later log it in the function, the name variable is coming back as 'currentTarget' instead of the name attribute I assign in in my renderHexTextField function, and the value is undefined.

I render a number of different text fields by calling the renderHexTextField function, which takes in two params. The first is the value of the

If it was working as intented, the name variable would equal the 'hoverFontColor' string from my return statement, which would then be passed into handleChange as a key for the css object, and value would manipulate the mobx state tree.

Any help is appreciated!

edit** I forgot to mention that the TextField component is a [MaterialUI component](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/)

SOLUTION EDIT** -- My handleChange was bound to a debounce. I had to update my onChange component attribute so event.persist() ran before this.handleChange. Thank you Praveen and Chris!

```
return (
   this.renderHexTextField(css.hoverFontColor, 'hoverFontColor')
)


  private renderHexTextField(input: string, name: string) {
    // name parameter used to specify which state in handleChange function
    if (name === 'fontType' || this._throwHexErr(input) === 'True') {
      // If hex format is correct, render normal text field
      return (
        <TextField
          required={true}
          id="standard-required"
          margin="normal"
          name={name}
          placeholder={input}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      )
    } else {
      // else render error text field
      return (
        <TextField
          error={true}
          id="standard-error"
          margin="normal"
          name={name}
          placeholder={input}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      )
    }
  }

  private handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const { name, value } = event.currentTarget
    const { store } = this.props
    const currentBot = store.bots.current
    if (currentBot) {
      const id = currentBot._id
      const css: any = toJS(currentBot.theme.css)
      log('css obj >> ', css)
      if (css) {
        css[name] = value
        log('handleChange >>> ', name, value, css)
        currentBot.patchCSS(id, css)
      }
    } else {
      log('No current bot in handleChange')
    }
  }

  private _validateHex(hexcode: string, regex: any) {
    // Regex Testing Function
    log('validating hex')
    return regex.test(hexcode)
  }

  private _throwHexErr(userInput: string) {
    // Return True or Error depending on result of Regex Test
    const regex = /^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{6}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{3})$/
    if (this._validateHex(userInput, regex)) {
      return 'True'
    } else {
      return 'Error'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same trouble recently, I have used `React.FormEvent<HtmlInputElement>`. That gives me `event.currentTarget.name` from the interface. Does that help?

So just to elaborate, try changing `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>` to `React.FormEvent<HtmlInputElement>`.

Comment: Thanks Chris but unfortunately that didn't work. I'm using Material UI, and it looks like TextField is expecting a type of React.ChangeEvent. Maybe I can tweak it in the d.ts file?

Comment: I would avoid changing the .d.ts file. I am not familiar with Material UI, but it feels like you are along the right lines. And `target` instead of `currentTarget` seems to fit with the material-ui docs. Are you using visual studio code? If you hover over the onChange on the Component, does it verify that event should have type of `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`? It could be that material-ui provide you with a custom type to use instead.

Comment: Yes it does verify React.ChangeEvent. I'll take another look at the TextField API docs

Comment: I think you are along the right lines. I would shy away from using 'any' type, it is an escape hatch and kind of defeats the point of using a type system. Should all fail and the code works, it would be better to create a matching interface that you own, that describes the types you expect. At least if you make a change down the line, it will cover you from making a mistake

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change

```
const { name, value } = event.currentTarget
```

to

```
const { name, value } = event.target
```

or

```
const name = event.target.name;
const value = event.target.value;
```

This should work fine

```
private handleChange = (event: any): void => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    const { store } = this.props
    const currentBot = store.bots.current
    if (currentBot) {
      const id = currentBot._id
      const css: any = toJS(currentBot.theme.css)
      log('css obj >> ', css)
      if (css) {
        css[name] = value
        log('handleChange >>> ', name, value, css)
        currentBot.patchCSS(id, css)
      }
    } else {
      log('No current bot in handleChange')
    }
  }
```

also, do

```
<TextField
          error={true}
          id="standard-error"
          margin="normal"
          name={name}
          placeholder={input}
          onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
        />
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, I tried that, and I'm getting a typescript error that `Type 'EventTarget & HTMLInputElement' cannot be used as an index type.`

Pretty new to typescript - do I need to define an interface in the document?

Comment: (event: any) should fix that

Comment: So after changing (event: any) and setting name and value equal to event.target.name and event.target.value, I am getting an error that event.target is null:    

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`

Comment: I also tried creating a custom attribute on the TextField component called data-name, but I am running into the same error when I type into the TextField that event.target is null

Comment: Same error. I've also included event.persist() in the handleChange function

Comment: @MatthewPorter i have edited my answer , please try this

Comment: haha.... that's like step one of learning how to do onChange events. I can't believe I forgot that. let me try it out.

Comment: Well I fixed the name issue by adding a name parameter and passing in the name from the parent function. But that is just a workaround, because I am still running into the same error for event.target.value

Comment: I figured it out - my handleChange was bound to a debounce, and it was trying to update the state tree before the debounce was finished. I think.

Comment: So I had to add event.persist() in my onChange attribute before calling handleChange

Answer (score 0):

See my solution edit above. My handleChange function was bound to a debounce, so I had to include event.persist() in the onChange attribute.

Answer (score 0):

use `e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name')`

example:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('name'))
}
```